# Loop Through Array of Strings (Actually an Array of Array of Strings, e.g. `{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arrays, foreach, strings

I'm drawing stones on a Go (game) board with [SGF](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html) coordinates (which I only managed to do from the the help people gave me on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441)) like this `\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{ab}`.

However, there might be many stones per diagram, so it would be practical to also have another macro like this: `\drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}` (the colors typically alternate, but sometimes it's more practical to have a list of black coordinates and then white's).

Here's what I'm trying right now, though it doesn't work (I mean, it does work, just not with the new macro):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \newcommand\stringToCoordX[1]{
    \int_from_alph:e{\use_i:nn#1}
  }
  \newcommand\stringToCoordY[1]{
    ~\int_from_alph:e{\use_ii:nn#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
    node[color = white] {1};
}

% Example usage: `drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`
\newcommand{\drawStonesFromSgfCoords}[1]{
  \foreach \coords in {#1}{
    \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{{\coords}[0]}{{\coords}[1]}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    
    % \drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's the proper way of accessing or passing arrays (within a loop)?

(I'm using PGF's `\foreach` because that's what I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is a better idea to process the nested `clist` (a comma-separated list) via expl tools here since tools already exist there to handle such lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  % Example usage: `drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawStonesFromSgfCoords}{ m }{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \exp_args:Noo \drawStoneFromSgfCoords { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }
      
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    \drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some notes on the used commands (a nice overview and an exhaustive documentation can be found in the [L3 Interfaces PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)):

- `\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }` stores a `clist` (a comma-separated list) in a token variable to make it accessible. In the example case, `{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}` is stored as `clist` in the token variable `\l_tmpa_clist`.
- `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ... }` loops over every item in the `clist` (stored in the token variable) and executes the code between the curly braces. The current item is accessed via `#1` (`##1` in the code example, because it is nested one level deeper).
- `\clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl` grabs the first item of the `clist` and stores it in a token variable (`l_tmpa_tl`). It then removes this item from the `clist`.
- `\exp_args:Noo \drawStoneFromSgfCoords { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }` first expands the two token variables and inserts the result as arguments to `\drawStoneFromSgfCoords`.

So, lets look what happens step by step if we say `\drawStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`:

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawStonesFromSgfCoords}{ m }{

    % store {{black, ab}, {white, cd}} in \l_tmpa_clist 
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }

    % loop over items in \l_tmpa_clist 
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {

      % store {black, ab} in \l_tmpb_clist
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }

      % store black in \l_tmpa_tl and remove item from clist
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 

      % store ab in \l_tmpb_tl and remove item from clist
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 

      % expand \l_tmpa_tl and \l_tmpb_tl so that we get
      % \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
      \exp_args:Noo \drawStoneFromSgfCoords { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }

      % repeat this loop for the next item in the clist in \l_tmpa_clist

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind me asking about tips on how to understand this expl3 syntax? Could you maybe write some bullet points on what exactly those macros do? I feel like if the problem changes slightly I wouldn't be able to adapt this by myself at all.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I added some explanations for the code I added to the existing code.

Comment: Amazing. You went above and beyond. Thank you so much for the helpful explanations!