# How to do an if after an `exp:args` in expl3

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3

Following [this answer by @JasperHabicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708961/64441), in my code, I would like to add an option to that macro so, depending on a flag I can execute either `\drawMoveFromSgfCoords` or `\drawStoneFromSgfCoords`. I still don't know much about expl3, so this is kinda my pseudocode:

```tex
% Parameters
%
% 1: array of {<black | white>, <coordinates}
%
% Example usage: `drawStonesOrMovesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}{true}`
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawStonesOrMovesFromSgfCoords}{ m }{ m }{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      % I'm trying to fix what's in-between parentheses below:
      \exp_args:Noo (\bool_if:NN ##2 \drawStoneFromSgfCoords \drawMoveFromSgfCoords) { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here's a more or less complete example (if you know the syntax, this is probably gonna be unnecessary):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm]
    node[color = \UseName{not#1}]
      {\themoveCounter};

  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  % Example usage: `drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ m }{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \exp_args:Noo \drawStoneFromSgfCoords { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }
      
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    \drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is far from clear: what are you actually trying to do? I suspect that the command you want is: `\str_case:nn`.

Comment: I've added a comment to the first code block. I'm trying to basically do a ternary on those 2 macros.

Comment: you shouldn't normally need `exp_args:...` explicitly, and `\exp_args:Noo`  is a bit odd as `o` just expand one step whereas normally ou want full expansion `e` if you want it at all but `\exp_args:Noo (\bool_if:NN ##`  applies `N` to `(`, `o` to `\bool_if:NN` and `#` which probably wan't the intention?

Comment: Also, `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawStonesOrMovesFromSgfCoords}{ m }{ m }{ ...}` won't work. You need to pass the specification of all the arguments (`m` etc.) as a single argument. So you'd need `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawStonesOrMovesFromSgfCoords}{ m  m }{ ...}`. Your code never actually uses the second argument. Probably you wanted `#2` rather than `##2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
  % There is no point in doing \NewExpandableDocument as \clist_set:Nn and
  % \clist_pop:NN and \clist_map_inline:Nn are not fully expandable.
  \NewDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ s m }{
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "true" in case a star was provided.
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "false" in case no star was provided.
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \IfBooleanTF {#1} { \exp_args:NVV \drawStoneFromSgfCoords } 
                        { \exp_args:NVV \drawMoveFromSgfCoords } 
      \l_tmpa_tl  \l_tmpb_tl
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Or:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
  % There is no point in doing \NewExpandableDocument as \clist_set:Nn and
  % \clist_pop:NN and \clist_map_inline:Nn are not fully expandable.
  \NewDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ s m }{
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "true" in case a star was provided.
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "false" in case no star was provided.
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \exp_args:Nc
      \exp_args:NVV
      {draw\IfBooleanTF {#1}{Stone}{Move}FromSgfCoords}
      \l_tmpa_tl  \l_tmpb_tl
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you like it complicated, you can nest `\exp_args:NnV \use:n {...} \Variable` within the `n`-argument of `\exp_args:NnV`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
  % There is no point in doing \NewExpandableDocument as \clist_set:Nn and
  % \clist_pop:NN and \clist_map_inline:Nn are not fully expandable.
  \NewDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ s m }{
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "true" in case a star was provided.
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "false" in case no star was provided.
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \exp_args:NnV 
         \use:n 
         {
           \exp_args:NnV 
              \use:n 
              { \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\drawStoneFromSgfCoords} {\drawMoveFromSgfCoords} } 
              \l_tmpa_tl
         } 
         \l_tmpb_tl
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here is a complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm]
    node[color = \UseName{not#1}]
      {\themoveCounter};

  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  % There is no point in doing \NewExpandableDocument as \clist_set:Nn and
  % \clist_pop:NN and \clist_map_inline:Nn are not fully expandable.
  \NewDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ s m }{
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "true" in case a star was provided.
    % The s argument, denoted by #1, is "false" in case no star was provided.
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
      \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
      \IfBooleanTF {#1} { \exp_args:NVV \drawStoneFromSgfCoords } 
                        { \exp_args:NVV \drawMoveFromSgfCoords } 
      \l_tmpa_tl  \l_tmpb_tl
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    % The unstarred variant does \drawMoveFromSgfCoords:
    \drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    %\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    % The starred variant does \drawStoneFromSgfCoords:
    \drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords*{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it this way myself, but the following code works with relatively conservative changes to your original.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ mm }{
  \int_from_alph:n {  #1 }
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ mm }{
  \int_from_alph:n { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX#2 - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY#2 - 1}
  
  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
  ({\x * 1.8cm},{\y * 1.8cm})
  circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX#2 - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY#2 - 1}
  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
  ({\x * 1.8cm},{\y * 1.8cm})
  circle [radius = 0.2575cm]
  node[color = \UseName{not#1}]
  {\themoveCounter};
  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Example usage: `drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}`
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords}{ sm }{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }
    \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
    \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl 
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
    {
      \ExpandArgs { VV } \drawStoneFromSgfCoords \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl 
    }{
      \ExpandArgs { VV } \drawMoveFromSgfCoords \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl  
    }   
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

  \drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords{{black,ab}, {white, cd}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

  \drawMovesOrStonesFromSgfCoords*{{black, ab}, {white, cd}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two boards with stones]