Labels on Go-Board
I wanted to recreate this board here

and here is my code:
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{psgo}

\begin{document}
\setgounit{0.4cm} 
\begin{psgopartialboard}
{(1,1)(19,11)}
\stone{white}{c}{3}
\stone{white}{d}{2}
\stone{white}{d}{4}
\stone{white}{d}{7}
\stone{white}{d}{8}
\stone{black}{d}{3}
\stone{white}{e}{6}
\stone{white}{e}{9}
\stone{black}{e}{7}
\stone{black}{e}{8}
\stone{white}{f}{6}
\stone{white}{f}{10}
\stone{black}{f}{7}
\stone{black}{f}{9}
\stone{white}{g}{6}
\stone{white}{g}{10}
\stone{black}{g}{7}
\stone{black}{g}{8}
\stone{black}{g}{9}
\stone{white}{h}{6}
\stone{white}{h}{10}
\stone{white}{h}{7}
\stone{black}{h}{9}
\stone{white}{j}{10}
\stone{black}{j}{7}
\stone{black}{j}{9}
\stone{black}{j}{8}
\stone{white}{k}{9}
\stone{white}{k}{8}
\stone{black}{k}{1}
\stone{black}{k}{2}
\stone{white}{l}{1}
\stone{white}{l}{2}
\stone{black}{l}{3}
\stone{white}{m}{1}
\stone{black}{m}{2}
\stone{black}{q}{5}
\stone{black}{q}{6}
\stone{black}{q}{7}
\stone{black}{q}{8}
\stone{black}{r}{5}
\stone{white}{r}{6}
\stone{white}{r}{7}
\stone{black}{r}{8}
\stone{black}{s}{4}
\stone{black}{s}{8}
\stone{black}{t}{4}
\stone{black}{t}{8}
\stone{white}{t}{5}
\stone{white}{t}{6}
\stone{white}{t}{7}
\stone{white}{s}{5}
\stone{white}{s}{7}
\end{psgopartialboard} 

\end{document}

But as you can see, the labeling is not correct, the letters are big and instead of a i there is a j. Also, there are labels on the left side.

How can I fix this?

Edit: There is also the label question if we are in the middle of the board:

This does not work:
\begin{psgopartialboard}
{(5,5)(15,14)}
\stone{black}{g}{9} 
\stone{black}{j}{8} 
\stone{black}{j}{10} 
\stone{black}{j}{13} 
\stone{black}{k}{7} 
\stone{black}{k}{11} 
\stone{black}{l}{9} 
\stone{black}{m}{6} 
\stone{black}{m}{12} 
\stone{white}{h}{9} 
\stone{white}{j}{9} 
\stone{white}{k}{9} 
\stone{white}{k}{8} 
\stone{white}{k}{10} 
\stone{white}{k}{12} 
\stone{white}{l}{7} 
\stone{white}{l}{10} 
\stone{white}{l}{11} 
\end{psgopartialboard}


Welcome to the TeX.SE. community? Why do you using tikz? There are two main package igo and psgo. I suggest to switch to https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/psgo/psgomanual.pdf

@Sebastiano Thanks! I try my best to learn it. Do you know how to only have labels one one side?

I think that the best starting point is edit your code and write a minimal working example.

@Sebastiano Now the only problem is the labeling! I figured out the rest...

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708773/parsing-the-main-branch-of-single-branched-sgf-files-with-regex

In the psgo package the position marks on the x and y axes are placed by two commands \xpositionmarks and \ypositionmarks. You can renew (i.e., modify) these commands to make the required changes. This can be done in a number of ways but an easy way is to copy the original definition from the package source code, change \newcommand into \renewcommand and make the changes you want. This new code should be placed in your own document just below \usepackage{psgo}.
The y position marks are the simplest: in the original there are two drawing commands for the left and right side of the board.
% original command
\newcommand{\ypositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
      \edef\ypos{\arabic{#1}}%
      \addtocounter{#1}{-1}%
      \rput[r](-\goxunit,\value{#1}){\golabelformat{\ypos}}%
      \setlength{\tmplx}{#2\goxunit}%
      \rput[l](\tmplx,\value{#1}){\golabelformat{\ypos}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%

You can just remove the second command.
% modified command
\renewcommand{\ypositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
      \edef\ypos{\arabic{#1}}%
      \addtocounter{#1}{-1}%
      \rput[r](-\goxunit,\value{#1}){\golabelformat{\ypos}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%

The x position is a bit more involved. In the package the i is skipped but the j is there. Now you want to include the i but skip the j, i.e., do the skip one letter later.
In the code there is a check to do the skip at position 8, now you want to change that to position 9.
Furthermore the letters are drawn using \Alph, which means upper case letter. You need to change that into \alph, which means lower case letter.
This creates a further issue that the letters are no longer vertically aligned, for example the b is higher than the a in lower case and they are printed top-aligned with \rput[t]. You need to change this to print them at the baseline with \rput[B].
Original command:
\newcommand{\xpositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \rput[t](\value{#1},-\goyunit){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 8}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\Alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\Alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \setlength{\tmply}{#2\goyunit}%
      \rput[B](\value{#1},\tmply){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 8}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\Alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\Alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%

With the three changes:
\renewcommand{\xpositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \rput[B](\value{#1},-\goyunit){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 9}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \setlength{\tmply}{#2\goyunit}%
      \rput[B](\value{#1},\tmply){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 9}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%

Full MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psgo}
\renewcommand{\xpositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \rput[B](\value{#1},-\goyunit){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 9}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \setlength{\tmply}{#2\goyunit}%
      \rput[B](\value{#1},\tmply){%
        \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{#1} > 9}%
          {\addtocounter{#1}{1}\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
          {\golabelformat{\alph{#1}}}%
        \addtocounter{#1}{-1}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%
    
\renewcommand{\ypositionmarks}[2]{%
    \whiledo{\value{#1} < #2}{%
      \addtocounter{#1}{1}%
      \edef\ypos{\arabic{#1}}%
      \addtocounter{#1}{-1}%
      \rput[r](-\goxunit,\value{#1}){\golabelformat{\ypos}}%
      \stepcounter{#1}%
      }%
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{psgopartialboard}
{(1,1)(19,11)}
\stone{white}{c}{3}
\stone{white}{d}{2}
\stone{white}{d}{4}
\stone{white}{d}{7}
\stone{white}{d}{8}
\stone{black}{d}{3}
\stone{white}{e}{6}
\stone{white}{e}{9}
\stone{black}{e}{7}
\stone{black}{e}{8}
\stone{white}{f}{6}
\stone{white}{f}{10}
\stone{black}{f}{7}
\stone{black}{f}{9}
\stone{white}{g}{6}
\stone{white}{g}{10}
\stone{black}{g}{7}
\stone{black}{g}{8}
\stone{black}{g}{9}
\stone{white}{h}{6}
\stone{white}{h}{10}
\stone{white}{h}{7}
\stone{black}{h}{9}
\stone{white}{j}{10}
\stone{black}{j}{7}
\stone{black}{j}{9}
\stone{black}{j}{8}
\stone{white}{k}{9}
\stone{white}{k}{8}
\stone{black}{k}{1}
\stone{black}{k}{2}
\stone{white}{l}{1}
\stone{white}{l}{2}
\stone{black}{l}{3}
\stone{white}{m}{1}
\stone{black}{m}{2}
\stone{black}{q}{5}
\stone{black}{q}{6}
\stone{black}{q}{7}
\stone{black}{q}{8}
\stone{black}{r}{5}
\stone{white}{r}{6}
\stone{white}{r}{7}
\stone{black}{r}{8}
\stone{black}{s}{4}
\stone{black}{s}{8}
\stone{black}{t}{4}
\stone{black}{t}{8}
\stone{white}{t}{5}
\stone{white}{t}{6}
\stone{white}{t}{7}
\stone{white}{s}{5}
\stone{white}{s}{7}
\end{psgopartialboard}
\end{document}

Result:


This looks perfect, but is it possible to make the letters and numbers larger? Like in the original picture? Also, they do not seem so close to the edge...

@Sokoban It wouldn't make sense to put the markers closer to the edge. Because the piece markers overlap the edge, they need to allow for that overlap (see e.g. the k l m labels).

@Sokoban you can make the labels larger by adding \renewcommand{\golabelformat}[1]{{\sffamily\large #1}} or even \renewcommand{\golabelformat}[1]{{\sffamily\Large #1}} (which will overlap, you should move the row of letters down in that case). However, I'm not sure I understand why you want the output to be as close as possible to the example that you found - many design choices for displaying a Go board are in some sense arbitrary and equally valid, the 1993 article looks good but the psgo defaults are also fine in my opinion.

@Marijn Thank you! Yes I think it looks fine. I really like the original though and I always try to be close to it. In print it is more readable if the letters and numbers are bigger imo.

One last question, I want to print a board where there are go stones in the middle of the board but there are still labels. The partialboard setting does not really work here. I added a picture in the question.
